# Graphics on the left corner and caption next to it

Tags: graphics, captions, includegraphics

I want to create this using latex
[image]

I tried SCfigure and subfigure but I couldn't do it.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
   \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig1}
      \captionsetup{width=1.5\linewidth}
      \caption*{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
  \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `\caption` inside a `minipage` right next to the image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
    \vspace*{-\abovecaptionskip}
    
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec non tempus nibh. 
      Aliquam consequat ultrices bibendum. Phasellus tincidunt, sem id finibus ultricies, 
      nisi purus pharetra turpis, in convallis massa ipsum at ipsum. Curabitur convallis est 
      quis tellus porta, vel dignissim nisi pulvinar. Quisque viverra nec mi in euismod. 
      Donec pharetra lectus nec ornare vehicula. Quisque eu magna tristique, blandit ipsum 
      at, finibus tellus. Pellentesque dapibus odio sed nulla aliquet, eu sodales ex 
      sollicitudin. Phasellus pulvinar sed ante vel tincidunt.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It give an error "Option clash for package adjustbox. \fancyhead" @Werner

Comment: @Norman: Can you provide a minimal document I can use to replicate your issue?